# python get parameters of passed function

Tags: python, meta, inspect

I want to pass a function, f(a=1,b=2) into g and use the 'a' value in g

```
def f(a,b): pass

def g(f): #print f.a
```

`g(f(1,2))` should result in an output of 1

I looked into the inspect module but can't seem to get hold of f in g

This is as far as my programming knowledge has got me :

```
def g(f):
  print(list(inspect.signature(f).parameters.keys()))
```

`g(f(1,2))` results in: `TypeError: None is not a callable object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `g` appropriately, so the `f`, *as a function*, is an argument:

```
g(f, 1, 2)
```

Now work that into your function:

```
def g(f, *args):
  print(list(inspect.signature(f).parameters.keys()))
```

... and from here, you can iterate through `args` to make the proper call to `f`.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: yes that helps a lot given i can not access the parameters of f in g directly...thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. When you call `g(f(1,2))`, `f(1,2)` is finished before `g` runs. The only way this would be possible would be for `f` to return its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def f(a, b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Then define **wrapper** as:

```
def wrapper(func, a, b):
    func(a, b)
```

Or if you want more flexibility use *args:

```
def wrapper(func, *args):
    func(*args)
```

That flexibility comes with some risk if the number of arguments don't match. Which means you'll need to take care that all **func** passed to **wrapper** have a consistent signature.

You could use **kwargs which would help with the above, then:

```
def wrapper(func, **kwargs):
    func(**kwargs)
```

Then calls to **wrapper** would look like:

```
wrapper(f, a=1, b=2)
```

This would allow for more flexibility and signature of **func** could vary as needed.

You could turn **wrapper** into a *decorator* but that's another question.